# How do you measure the chemical potential?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

It is clear how to measure thermodynamics quantities such as temperature, pressure, energy, particle number and volume.  But I have no idea how to measure [chemical potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential).

Could someone please provide some examples of how one could measure the chemical potential?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential read the discovery part might be of help

Comment: You said you can measure energy, but can you really?  Please describe how you would measure, say, internal energy U.  You certainly can't measure it directly.  And all you can do indirectly is measure the change in U.  The same goes for H, S, and G.  And, since G is the basis for chemical potential, you can determine chemical potential indirectly relative to a reference state (at least for an ideal gas).  Is this adequate?

Comment: @ChetMiller T and P are also defined as derivatives of S, does that mean that T and P can also only be determined relative to a reference state?

Comment: @JuanPerez No.  S is determined up to an arbitrary constant.  So when you take the derivative of S, the derivative of the constant is zero.

Comment: @ChetMiller but $\mu$ is also a derivative of S (or U or G) so then it should also be free of any constant... I really don't see what's so unique about $\mu$ that it can't be absolute like T or P.

Comment: @JuanPerez $\mu$ or G does not have to be absolute to use it in any practical calculation of chemical or phase equilibrium.  If you think it does have to be absolute in order to handle practical applications, please cite an example.

Comment: @ChetMiller I don't think $\mu$ *needs* to be absolute for practical applications, I agree with you there. Nevertheless it *is* absolute, I think, or at least as absolute as $P$, because the math behind both is identical.

Comment: @JuanPerez The math behind it is not identical.  If you think $\mu$ is absolute, please define the condition under which the absolute value of $\mu$ is always zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't measure chemical potentials but that's OK because the actual value of the potential is not important, what matters is its *difference* from some other state. So, chemical potentials are *compared*. For example, in vapor-liquid equilibrium the chemical potential of the liquid component is equal to the chemical potential of the vapor component. If the vapor phase can be treated as an ideal gas we can *calculate* (not measure) its chemical potential. If it is not an ideal gas we need some other equation of state along with suitable assumptions about the interaction of components in order to do the calculation. It is also possible to calculate chemical potentials by *computer simulation*.

The general procedure to measure *difference* in the chemical potential is to compare it to some standard reference. Two standard references are in common use: *ideal-gas state* and *ideal solution*. In both cases the chemical potential of the reference state is
$$
   \mu_i = \mu_i^0 + RT \ln x_i
$$
where $x_i$ is the mol fraction of the component and $\mu_i^0$ is the chemical potential of the pure component at the same temperature and pressure. One then calculates the departure of the chemical potential from the reference state using auxiliary properties such as activity coefficients, fugacity coefficients, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can measure it indirectly by using other extensive quantities and applying thermodynamic relations (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_thermodynamic_equations). For instance, you could use $$\mu = (\frac{\partial G}{\partial N})_{p,T}$$

As for measuring it directly, it is not possible to measure it directly.

You can check the answer in [Is there a tool to measure the chemical potential of a system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231859/is-there-a-tool-to-measure-the-chemical-potential-of-a-system) for a reason about the last point.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to measure chemical potential directly. Chemical potential is *exactly* analogous to pressure, via the fundamental relation S(U, V, N).

While P is what is equalized under a moving wall, $\mu$ is what is equalized under a permeable wall.

While V is what changes to equalize P, N is what changes to equalize $\mu$.

We can measure P by placing it next to a reference system via a moveable wall and see if V increases, decreases, or stays the same. Then we say our system has smaller, greater, or equal pressure than the reference.

We can measure $\mu$ by placing it next to a reference system via a permeable wall and see if N increases, decreases, or stays the same. Then we say our system has smaller, greater, or equal chemical potential than the reference.

We will see the pressure of an ideal gas decreases linearly with N. Since the minimum N is zero, the corresponding minimal pressure of an ideal gas is that with zero N. So we then simply define zero pressure as the pressure of an empty container.

The $\mu$ of an ideal gas increases with ln(P), so it is undefined at zero P (it approaches negative infinity). So there's no clear system we should take as having zero $\mu$.

Nevertheless, we can measure the (relative) chemical potential of any system by this method. It is important that the other thermodynamic variables remain constant as we measure.